# How to get the value of a textbox on keypress event in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, key-events

I am making a chrome extension in which I want to do some string replacement in the text when the enter key is pressed in a focussed textarea. Here is the code snippet:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("ChatTabsPagelet").getElementsByTagName("textarea"),i;
matchClass = "uiTextareaAutogrow";

for (i in elems) {
    if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')> -1) {
    text = elems[i].value;          
            elems[i].onkeyup = function(evt) {
              if(evt.keyCode == 13){
               alert(elems[i].value);
              }
      };
   }
}
```

Basically I am looking for all the textareas with the class *uiTextareaAutogrow* and I just want to access their values when the enter key is pressed in any of those textareas. However, I always get *undefined* in the alert box when I try the extension out on a webpage. I guess the keyup event is fired but it is not able to get a handle to the particular textarea. Where am I going wrong?

Note: I am keen on using javascript only(not jquery) as I want the extension to be really light.

Comment: You should try using JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example should do the trick! ([see a working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/VChj8/)).

You shouldn't use `for..in` with array-like objects as the order cannot be guaranteed. Also when the value of an element is referenced in a dynamic function you need to use `this.value`.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
matchClass = "uiTextareaAutogrow";
for(var i = 0, n = elems.length; i < n; i++) { // <---- simple for loop
    if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')> -1) {
             elems[i].onkeyup = function(evt) {
                  if(evt.keyCode == 13){
                      alert(this.value);
                   }
            }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You my friend @QF_Developer are a savior. It works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help.